# Using jQuery Templates and wiring up events after render

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery Templates successfully but I have a blur function that is not getting called on the new elements being added to the page.  I assume its because they are not wired up to it for some reason.

Do I need to do something to fix it or should Ichange the blur function to use jQuery live?

```
$('.serial').blur(function () {
//Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) on elements that are added after the DOM has finished loading.

bind() or aliases such as blur() only affect elements in the DOM at the time of calling.

eg: `$('.serial').live('blur', function(){ /* do stuff */ });`